# ListView reaches end then stop scrolling and start scrolling the rest of the page Flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, dart

I have a `ListView` inside another ListView, basically something to read inside a scrollable page.

I would like to insert the option to stop scrolling when the end of the `ListView` is reached. If the user keep scrolling then the rest of the page should start to scroll.

Do you know how this could be reached? I saw there is a `physics` attribute but isn't clear how to set it. But I think this should be the answer in some way...

Comment: there's an attribute called `primary`, set that to `true` and check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just set `physics: ClampingScrollPhysics()` to the child ListView. It creates scroll physics that prevent the scroll offset from exceeding the bounds of the content. More about ListView and its physics refer to : https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-listview-and-scrollphysics-a-detailed-look-7f0912df2754